# Contador de caracteres con TypesScript

Tags: ionic, typescript, angular6

soy nuevo por aquí. Me interesa saber si alguno sabe como hacer un contador de caracteres en un textarea con typescript. Ya que no hago en JavaScript y con Php. Pero ahora estoy usando ionic 4, Angular 6 y TypeScript.
Gracias de antemano por el apoyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer un contador de caracteres el procedimiento que yo uso el siguiente:

En la archivo de la página agrego el siguiente código:

```
export class HomePage{

 private contador = 0 //Agrego esta linea

 constructor(){}

 // Agrego la siguiente función
 onKey(event){
   this.contador = event.target.value.length
  }
}
```

El caso de la vista solamente hay que agrega un atributo al input o al textarea

```
<textarea name="" (keyup)="onKey($event)"></textarea>
<span>{{contador}}</span>
```